# HTML Email Validation?

Tags: php, html-email, standards, w3c-validation

I guess this is a standards question and not a specific coding question.

I wanted to know if I needed to validate the HTML with something like [W3C HTML Validation](http://validator.w3.org/)? If I send the DOCTYPE and META tags in the HTML email it doesn't render the HTML in the email properly but validates with W3C, but if I remove the DOCTYPE and META tags the HTML renders properly in the email client but now doesn't validate with W3C. Is this something that I should be concerned with or is this standard practice?

In [PHP I'm doing Example #4](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) if you need to see how to send a HTML email in PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing standard in HTML e-mail at this time.  While it is good to target towards valid HTML, you'll find there are lots of modifications you will need to make for your e-mail to work.

Target the client, not the specification, in this instance.

Perhaps some day valid HTML e-mail will be a reality, but it isn't for now.

Comment: I haven't found much need to validate HTML to begin with... at the end of the day Google can get what it needs, that's all that matters.

Answer (score -1):

For HTML emails, currently it's best to use tables for any kind of layout you might want to do. Mailchimp has a few templates that can get you started for some basic email layouts.

[MailChimp Email Templates](http://www.mailchimp.com/resources/html_email_templates/)

Comment: Sorry not really asking how to code a HTML email, but is there any validation needed or is it the 'Whatever works' approach?

Comment: It's the "whatever works" approach. Sometimes though, you may want to link to a browser friendly version of the email and that is when you'll obviously want it to validate.